# Microsoft asp c# RegEx escape multiple reserved characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, escaping

I just want a use of regex that will return true/false if a character exists in a string that is not a regularly type-able character.  This should be an easy thing to do shouldn't it?

I don't have pattern, pre se, I just want to know if any character exists that isn't in the list.

In the regular RegEx world I simply:

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z~`!@#$%\^ &*()_-+={\[}]|\\:;\"'<,>.?/] // <space> before the ampersand
```

...I know a little bloated but makes the point for this post...

I find you can't escape multiple reserved characters.
For instance, Regex ex = Regex.Escape("[") + Regex.Escape("^") will not hit on:
"st[eve" or "st^ve"

as in the following fails:

```
    string ss = Regex.Escape("[") + Regex.Escape("^");
    Regex rx = new Regex(ss);
    string s = "st^eve";
    rx.IsMatch(s));
```

as will any of these:

```
    string ss = Regex.Escape("[") + "[0-9]";
    Regex rx = new Regex(ss);
    string s1 = "st^eve"; rx.IsMatch(s1));
    string s2 = "st^ev0e; rx.IsMatch(s2));
    string s3 = "stev0e;  rx.IsMatch(s3));
```

But this is the only use of Microsoft c# Regex escaped characters that won't fail:

```
    string ss = Regex.Escape("^");
    Regex rx = new Regex(ss);
    string s = "st^eve"; rx.IsMatch(s));
```

Do I have to develop a separate test for EACH escape-necessary characters IN ADDITION TO a test for the non escaped characters?

Is this what other people are doing?

I'm open to ideas if there a better way?

Thanks for you consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks to @PMV.  He's input prompted me to do a bunch of tests.

This is apparently how it really works.

No matter what I tried I could not get double-quote nor single-quote to match unless those two where their own separate test.  And that actually makes sense thinking all the way back to 'C' language.

Note: in **no** case do you ***have*** to use `.Escape()`.  IMO having to use a function to create a string = "\[" for you is just silly anyway.  `.Escape() is not necessary on ^ nor { nor ] nor \ nor " nor '`.

```
    string ss = "[0-9A-Z~`!@#$%^& *()-_+={[}]|\\:;<,>.?/";
        // does not match ~ ss = ss + Regex.Escape("\"");
        // does not match ~ ss = ss + Regex.Escape("\'");
    ss = ss + "]";

    Regex rx = new Regex(ss);
        // rx = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape("\"") + "]");
        // works just as well as the line above ~ rx = new Regex("[\"]");
        // rx = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape("'") + "]");
    rx = new Regex("[']");

    string s = "ste've";
    Console.WriteLine("search string {0}", ss);
    Console.WriteLine("IsMatch {0}", rx.IsMatch(s));
```

So close to being awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you're generating as an expression.  Your example RegEx

```
string ss = Regex.Escape("[") + Regex.Escape("^");
```

is equivalent to:

```
string ss = @"\[\^";
```

That is, it's not looking for `[` **or** `^`, it's looking for `[` **followed by** `^`.  So `ste[^ve` would match.

If you want to match any string containing one or more of the characters, you need to add (non-escaped) brackets to create a set of characters, such as:

```
string ss = "[" + Regex.Escape("[") + Regex.Escape("^") + "]"
```

That is, you are asking the Regex engine to look for one character within the set of characters in the brackets.

Comment: Note that `Regex.Escape("-")` is "-", so code you have so far is good starting step for answer but not enough to be complete answer.

Comment: @PMV  Hey thanks. Poking a little deeper for your remark I see that Regex.Escape("[") simply equals "\[".  So one would think to just use "\[".  Also this fails:  'Regex reg = new Regex("[\"" + Regex.Escape("]") + "]"); string str = "s\"t[ev0e";'  And this fails: 'Regex reg = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape("\"") + Regex.Escape("]") + "]");' Where this doesn't: 'Regex reg = new Regex("[\"]");'  I'm not a dumb guy but this seems a little unstable.  Maybe inconstant is a better word.  I'm working through a number or combinations and building a number of test.  I can see I'll get what I need.